# Custom Domain for API Gateway not able to set 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

I am trying to setup a custom domain endpoint for API gateway published endpoint but not able to set.

I've followed all steps

- Custom domain DNS is managed by AWS (aws cannot own this as its a .ai URL)
- Created ACM Certificate for subdomain. (subdomain.host.ai)
- Add Custom API in API Gateway with Mapping to particular Stage
- Add A record for custom domain to point to "d-abcde12345.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"

What might be going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, don't quite follow question. So your domain resolves but it returns a 404?

Answer (score 1):

When you are pointing to a DNS hostname, rather than an IP, you need a CNAME record. More importantly, when you assign a custom domain to your API Gateway, it will create a CloudFront distribution for you and gives you a CloudFront endpoint: `E123CNFSOMETHING.cloudfront.net`. You need to create a CNAME record in your registrar dashboard to point to this address, not the API Endpoint:

```
FROM                        TO                                    TTL
subdomain                   E123CNFSOMETHING.cloudfront.net.      300
```

Comment: Not necessarily it is a CloudFront distribution - that is the case only if it's an edge-optimized domain. In this case, it's a regional domain hence the target domain is d-xxxxx.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com. Also, it is not imperative the record should be CNAME. It's up to you to decide whether A or CNAME record.